# Flickr RSS in Xcode

Tags: xcode, rss

Anyone have a code for this? just need a flickr album's rss content implemented. I dont even know where to start. I spent a lot of time messing around with objectiveflickr but I kept getting compile errors and was eventually casually advised by a pro that an RSS image feed would suffice. I suspected this originally but found no codes to start me off.

Comment: you want to get pictures from flickr

Comment: Hello @7251100 If you want flickr Interface the you can download it from here      http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Flickr-Interface.zip

Comment: Hello @7251100 If you want flickr Interface the you can download it from here      http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Flickr-Interface.zip

Comment: Yes, I basically just need the app to launch into my flickr feed. I tried these out but they pull up blanks in simulator even after i enter my key. Hmm...